# Firebase is not a constructor

Tags: typescript, firebase, angular

I am trying to integrate Firebase into my Angular 2 app but I keep getting this error that `Firebase is not a constructor`. Following is what I did:

1. Installed firebase using bower
2. Referenced the script in index.html.
3. Install firebase ambient typings
4. Created a Firebase service
5. Provided it through `bootstrap()`
6. Had it injected in a component

FirebaseService.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class FirebaseService
{
    dataRef: Firebase;
    constructor() {
        this.dataRef = new Firebase('https://boiling-inferno-1117.firebaseio.com/votes');
    }
}
```

boot.ts

```
bootstrap(App, [HTTP_PROVIDERS, 
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS, 
    IdentityService, 
    ApiService, 
    UrlService, 
    provide(FirebaseService, {useValue: new FirebaseService()})
])
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

app.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: 'app/app.html',
    directives: [AuthRouterOutlet, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class App {        
    constructor(private firebase:FirebaseService)
    {

    }        
}
```

Systemjs config:

```
System.config({
    defaultJSExtensions: true,
    map: {
        'jquery': 'vendors/js/jquery',
        'firebase': 'vendors/js/firebase'
    },
    packages: {
        angular2: { defaultExtension: false },
        rxjs: { defaultExtension: false }
    }
});
```

and importing `Firebase` like below:

`import * as Firebase from 'firebase';`

Any suggestion on what I can do to resolve this situation is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can we assume that this: provide(FirebaseService, {useValue: new FirebaseService()}) is a typo? Because you should be using providers and it take an array afterward. providers : [FirebaseService]

Comment: Could you also provide your SystemJS configuration? And the way you import the Firebase class? Thanks!

Comment: @R.Richards Tried that also. Same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would configure Firebase this way:

```
System.config({
  map: {
    firebase: '/node_modules/firebase/lib/firebase-web.js',
    (...)
  },
  (...)
});
```

and import it like this in the TypeScript file:

```
import * as Firebase from 'firebase';
```

See the doc of Angularfire2 for more details:

- https://github.com/angular/angularfire2

Comment: I have a gulp task that copies the `firebase-web.js` file from `node_modules` folder into my `dist/vendors/js` directory. So it seems its essentially the same as what you showed. Am I wrong?

Comment: In fact you specify the folder not the js file into your SystemJS configuration ;-) You need to map the js file.

Comment: `vendors/js/firebase` here firebase is the file name like firebase.js. Since, I have `defaultJSExtensions: true` enabled `.js` seems to be appended for me. That is why jquery from my config works just fine.